# CSS Animations - Moving multiple elements sequentially

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Just look some examples on how to animate multiple elements sequentially.  I want to show an element and then move it to a specific location and maybe add some spinning and repeat this for 25 elements.

I was looking at using Bounce.js for this but was wanting to get opinions to see if there is something better suited for this type of thing.

Comment: A good practice will be if you try to do it. Don't get me wrong, we love helping people. But it is really important to test your curiosity and finding a way of solving problems. And when ever you are stock, your questions will surely be answered. See the [How to, Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If it's a series of animations, where some are parallel while some are sequential, consider using [***mo.js***](http://mojs.io/)

Comment: Your question seems primarily opinion based. Please ask a clear question about something specific after you have tried.

Comment: Thanks, after looking at mo.js I think I will go that route.